# Why did my food and water level drop so much?

Tags: ps4, 7-days-to-die

While building a shelter, I decided to make it 2 stories and used a ladder to get to the 2nd story.

While at the top, and building in the sun, I'm constantly checking my food and water levels just to make sure my character was okay. At this point my character was roughly 95% on both water and food.

Well, a zombie showed up and I realized I didn't have my bow. So I had to descend my ladder to my chest and get my bow & arrows. Upon getting back to the 1st level my water and food dropped at least 25%-30% on each which I found was really odd.

After climbing back up and taking care of the zombie. I decided to try it again. I went down the ladder and lost about the same amount of water and food, another 25%. Surely I didn't fall from the second floor 2 times in a row, so I restored my health and water and tried a third time. Once again losing about another 25% on each. The climb up I am completely fine but descending drains my character.

And it was only 3 blocks high so it's not like it was a big drop if I really was falling. To counter this, I decided to make a flight of stairs and haven't had any issues since. **Is there a bug when descending a ladder that causes you to lose so much water and food levels?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug related to ladders that is currently being addressed and should be fixed in the next patch.

> Looks like climbing up a ladder knocks your food and hydration down 30 o/o. Went through 20 grilled meat on horde night since I have underground entrance to and from base.
>
> This is a known issue that the team are working on a expedited patch for.

(from [this thread](https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?49455-Food-ladder-bug))

Comment: I haven't played the game very much but I noticed in your answer the part of being underground?! I know you can shovel up dirt and stuff but I thought that was the extent of "underground".

Comment: I haven't played the game much either, so I wouldn't know any better than you, but from the way the posts are worded, it sounds like it...